# How to extend session based on activity?

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I am currently building a web portal that is protected via SimpleSAMLPHP. The issue I am having is that currently the session expires 1 hour after the user logs in. Does anyone know if it is possible to extend the SimpleSAML session each time the user clicks something so it signs out after 1 hour of inactivity instead of 1 hour after they have logged in?

Thanks in advance